# Computing $P(X+Y>1)$.

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent r.v., with marginal pdf $ f_X(x)=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(x)$, and $f_Y(y)=1/2 \ \mathbb{I}_{[0,2]}(y)$.

To compute $P(X+Y>1)=P(X>1-Y)=\int^1_0\int^1_{1-y} 1/2 \ dx \ dy$, with the limits in the integral given by $1\geq 1-y\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 1\geq y\geq 0$

I get the result of $1/4$. However, looking at the solution which uses the convolution of both densities, I get $3/4$. Where did I go wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your integral doesn't include the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : y>1\}$. By symmetry, $\mathbb P(Y>1)=\frac12$, so adding that to $\frac14$ yields $\frac34$, the correct answer.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the joint density is the product of the marginal densities. Hence

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X+Y>1) &= \iint\limits_{\left\{(s,t)\in\mathbb R^2\ : \ s+t>1\right\}} f_{X,Y}\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^2  f_Y(y)f_X(x)\ \mathsf dy \ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^2 \frac12\mathsf dy \ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac12\int_0^1 (1+x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac12\int_1^2 u\ \mathsf du\\
&= \frac14(4-1)\\
&= \frac34.
\end{align}